# how does frontend js methods call a backend api in magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, frontend

I'm new to PHP and Magento.

I am building a payment module. I have saved some encrypted credentials in the core_data table. i am currently able to retrieve these decrypted credentials with my method renderer via : **window.checkoutConfig.payment.name_of_module**. these are made available through my **Model>Ui>ConfigProvider.php**, where they return the configurations(decrypted).

**Problem :**

I can grab these credentials and make an XHR request via my JavaScript. But my decrypted credentials will be out on display on dev tools.

is there a way for my listen to the method in my method renderer, on click, which calls a Magento backend API to run a function. so that it does not need to be displayed?

SINCERELY APPRECIATE with clear examples as I am really finding it tough to go through the docs.